# Show value using knockout

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js

I am calling an action that returns a JSON object using the following Action

```
public async Task<JsonResult> GetProjects(int companyId) { }
```

writing the following sentence in javascript:

```
data.Name
```

I can see the correct value from the object but when I try to use its value using knockout I am getting a weird value:

```
<h2 id="companyName" data-bind="text: companyName"></h2>
```

The code for calling the action is the following:

```
$.get('Projects/GetProjects?companyId=' + param, function (data) {        
        ko.applyBindings(data);
        $('#detailsModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
```

"[object HTMLHeadingElement]"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should give some more info: what function call/ variable exactly outputs `[object HTMLHeadingElement]`? How do you go from `data.Name` to `companyName` (the JSON transfer)? is the latter a computed property? Where's the rest of the code? And why is the question tagged asp.net & c#?

Comment: @Tyblitz I have just updated the code. I tagged it asp.net-mvc because I am doing a call to a c# mvc controller that returns a json object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are binding `HTMLHeadingElement` to an h2, which is a `HTMLHeadingElement` itself.

If you log this:

```
console.log(companyName.outerHTML);
```

You will get a string close to `"<h2>ACME Corporation</h2>"`

So I guess the mistake come from your up-front work, when storing your data. You may convert `companyName` to its text value **when storing it into your database**.

[`HTMLHeadingElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLHeadingElement) inherits properties from [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) so you have access to `textContent` property, which is what you are looking for.

```
// Pseudo code: before storing your project
project.companyName = source.companyName.textContent
project.save()
```

If you don't want/can't do this up-front work, then you can do this while binding your value.

```
<h2 id="companyName" data-bind="text: companyName.textContent"></h2>
```